# Can we allow mathjax on the japanese stack exchange site so that questions about japanese mathematicans can be asked?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Some people might want to ask questions about the Japanese words for mathematical symbols.

Can we allow the MathJax plugin on the [Japanese stack exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com)?

```
¿What word do Japanese mathematicians use for $\color{teal}{\text{sets}}$? do they use for collections, number sets or number containers?

\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \cap \{4, 5, 6, 7\} = \{4, 5\}
    

$\{1, 2, 3\} \cup \{3, 4, 5\} = \{1, 2, 3, 4 , 5\}$

American mathematicians use the word $\color{teal}{\text{set}}$
```

[image: a screen capture taken from the math stack exchange]

More than [forty different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/610179) stack exchange forums allow people to write [MathJax](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax).

Therefore, the code implementing [MathJax](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) is already available and ready to use on stack exchange.

Most people can write Japanese and English without Mathjax, but some of us will ask questions about mathematics.

Comment: Can you give an example that 'demonstrates a serious need for MathJax' on Japanese SE? As far as I can imagine, on-topic questions on JSE would be able to get around using it by some copy-pasting. (Using images would do for questions on symbols themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the markdown for your set notation isn't working as intended as shown in the picture.

**In principle, I'm in favour** of being able to type math nicely on our site if the situation calls for it.

Practically, I'm afraid that the slashes or backslashes and curly braces **may mess up our existing methods** for furigana.

Furthermore, in the picture, the intersect (∩) symbol not appearing in the first example and the curly brace ({ }) not appearing in the second example does not inspire confidence in the markdown method.